# What is the penalty of contributing to a Coverdell ESA while earning over $110k MAGI?

Tags: united-states, irs, penalty, excess-contribution, coverdell-esa

Regarding [Coverdell Education Savings Account (ESA) (https://www.irs.gov)](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970/ch07.html)

> Q. Who can contribute to a Coverdell ESA?
>
> A. Generally, any individual (including the beneficiary) whose
>   modified adjusted gross income for the year is less than $110,000
>   ($220,000 in the case of a joint return).

How is the MAGI rule enforced and what is the penalty contributing to a Coverdell and earning over $110k MAGI?

Comment: Doesn't the linked doc reference a 6% penalty? In my opinion, that's what applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be surprised if it was similar to excess contributions. The fairmark.com article [More on Contributions to 
Coverdell Accounts](http://www.fairmark.com/college/saving/coverdell/contrib2.htm) suggests,
"Unless there is a timely corrective distribution, a 6% penalty tax applies to the excess contribution. What's more, the 6% penalty applies to the same excess every year until it's withdrawn from the Coverdell account (or treated as withdrawn as explained below)."

Answer (score 0):

The current answer tells you the penalty.

You also asked, how is it enforced? In my opinion, the excess deposit is easy, a broker sees the deposit and it's reported, just like IRA deposits or interest, etc. But the "over MAGI" is tougher to discover. The ESA can be funded by anyone. If I made over the MAGI limit, I can easily ask a close relative (grandma?) to make the deposit and find a way to get $2000 back to her. The 529 has no MAGI limit, and I suspect that the MAGA /ESA disqualification isn't high on the IRS radar.

Comment: It's possible to contribute less than $2K even though you earn more than $110K.

Comment: Well, no. The phaseout is from $95K - $110K for singles. Zero at $110K.

Comment: I see your point.